# Ruby 2.0 define_method in main

Tags: ruby

`define_method` is a method of `Module`.

In Ruby 2.0, `define_method` can be used at the top level; it doesn’t have to be inside a class or module.

```
define_method :kick do
  puts "method"
end
```

In Ruby 1.9, the `main` object does not have the method `define_method`.

```
define_method :kick
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `define_method' for main:Object
```

How does Ruby 2.0 implement this?

Comment: I should use a better example. Actually i just want to ask about `define_method`.

Comment: Why do you want to define something in the `main` context?

Comment: @txworking are you just curious, or is there an actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Stefan i just curious about this. This kind of answer should not appear here?

Comment: Isn't `main` actually `Kernel`?

Comment: @mohawkjohn `main` is instantiated, and `Kernel` is a module, and you can't instantiate a module.  `main.class` will return `Object`  And the documentation states "The Kernel module is included by class Object, so its methods are available in every Ruby object."

Answer (score 2):

I am also curious about this feature and use irb to try a little. Please take a look:

```
% irb
2.0.0-p353 :001 > method(:define_method)
=> #<Method: main.define_method> 
2.0.0-p353 :002 > private_methods(false)
=> [:public, :private, :include, :using, :define_method, :irb_exit_org, :default_src_encoding, :irb_binding] 
2.0.0-p353 :003 > singleton_class.private_instance_methods(false)
=> [:public, :private, :include, :using, :define_method, :irb_exit_org]
```

It shows that define_method is a private singleton method of the main object(the top level self).

Comment: Perhaps starting your irb output with `2.0.0-p481 :001 > self` with the output `=> main` might have made things a little clearer--because in ruby when you don't explicitly specify a receiver, ruby uses self, so in your code main is the object calling method(), private_methods(), and singleton_class(). ++ anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Building on uncutstone's sleuthing, define_method() is not inherited by main's singleton class:

```
class <<self
  p private_instance_methods(false)
end

--output:--
[:public, :private, :include, :using, :define_method]
```

...and as far as I can determine, if a method is not inherited, it has to be defined in the class. Note that when you include a module, ruby creates an anonymous class and inserts the module's defs in the anonymous class, then inserts the anonymous class directly above the including class in the method lookup chain, for instance:

```
module A
  def greet
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

class Dog
  include A
end

p Dog.instance_methods(false)
p Dog.instance_methods.grep(/^g/)

--output:--
[]
[:greet]
```

The output shows that greet() is an inherited method. But because define_method() was not inherited by main's singleton class, define_method() can't have been acquired by including a module.  Instead, it seems that define_method() must have been defined in main's singleton class.  So one way to implement that is to have ruby interpreter execute the following code before parsing your code:

```
class <<self
  def define_method(x, *y)
    #same code as in Module's define method
  end
end
```