# Ruby find max number w/o running method twice

Tags: ruby, function, max

I want to find the max number without running the function twice

```
def foo(num)
    num * 10
end

def bar
    x = 0
    for i in 0..5
         if foo(i) > x
             x = foo(i) # I don't want to run foo a second time
         end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the value of x:

```
define_method(:foo) { |x| x * 10 } 

(1..5).max_by { |x| foo(x) }                                             
#=> 5
```

If you want the value of f(x):

```
(1..5).map { |x| foo(x) }.max
#=> 50
```

Comment: Why I get (irb)? NoMethodError: undefined method `define_method' for main:Object.

Comment: Ruby version? Works in 2.X: `irb(main):002:0> define_method(:foo) { |x| 10 * x }
=> #<Proc:0x007fd04295f0c8@(irb):2 (lambda)>`

Comment: I tried in v 1.9.3. According to this exists http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-define_method.

Comment: I have found here the answer. Basically in version 2.x it allows to be defined outside of a class or module. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053338/ruby-2-0-define-method-in-main. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
def bar
  (1..5).map{|i| foo(i)}.max
end
```

This will traverse 1 to 5, and max a new enumerable with `foo(i)` instead of `i`, then return the max.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the result of the function as a variable, so you can use it later without calling the function again.

Applied to your code example, it would look like this:

```
#...
fooOfI = foo(i)
if fooOfI > x
    x = fooOfI
end
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the result of the method in a local variable.

```
def bar
  x = 0
  for i in 0..5
    foo_result = foo i
    if foo_result > x
      x = foo_result
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do some change in your code :

```
def foo(num)
    num * 10
end

def bar
    x = 0
    for i in 0..5
      _,x = [foo(i),x].sort #or you can write as x = [foo(i),x].max
    end
    x
end

p bar
# >> 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Elegant and simple

```
foo = -> x { x * 10 }
(1..5).map(&foo).max
# => 50
```

In one iteration (no so elegant but performs better)

```
def foo(num); num * 10; end;
(1..5).reduce(-1.0/0) { |a, e| f = foo(e); f > a ? f : a }
# => 50
```